# Why is this an non-injective immersion?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function
$$
f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2,\quad t\mapsto(t^2-1,t\cdot (t^2-1)).
$$

Why is this a (non-injective) immersion?

---

I think non-injective is clear, since, for example

$f(x)=f(y)$ does not imply $x=y$. For instance, $f(1)=f(-1)=(0,0)$.

But it is not clear to me why $f$ is an immersion.

I think I have to show that the total derivative
$$
df_p\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2
$$

at $p\in\mathbb{R}$

is injective. How to see that this total derivative is injective?

Maybe one way is to consider the Jacobian which should be

$$
Df_p=(2t,3t^2-1)^T
$$

This should have rank 2?

Is there another way to show the injectivity (maybe a graphical argument)?

Comment: It should have rank $1$, maximal possible.

Comment: Oh yes, in order to be an immersion it needs to have rank = 1.

Comment: But since we only have one column, rank = 1 is clear...

Comment: It could be less than $1$ still, if the column was 0 for some $t$. That does not happen, and you have to argue why.

Comment: Ok, I think I can manage that. I would be interested to see a "graphical" reason why the derivative is injective.

Comment: You might be able to use graphical means to show in some cases that it is not an immersion. In this case, just by looking at the image, no,. You have to look at the movement. That is a different thing, to show that the speed is not zero at any moment .

Comment: When plotting $(2t, 3t^2-1)$ for $-10\leq t\leq 10$, say, this gives some parabola. And I Wonder how this can be injective.

Comment: You can also plot it by $(2 s^3, 3 s^6 -1)$ and that is not an immersion at $s=0$. The image will be the same. That should give you some idea.

Comment: I do not See your Point. I Plotted the derivative and this dies not Look like an injective Funktion .

Comment: You're looking for the wrong function to be injective. The point is that, if you choose a particular $t$, then the map from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ given by the matrix $(2t,3t^2-1)^T$ is an injective linear map. There is no choice of $t$ for which it is not injective.

Comment: I meant the function $t\mapsto (2t, 3t^2-1)^T$. When plotting this, this gives a curve which looks like a parabola. Doesn‘ t it?

Comment: That looks like a parabola, but as a map from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is is injective, because different choices of $t$ give you different points on the parabola. That's still not what we need, though. If you pick any particular value of $t$, you get an injective linear map. For example, if $t=1$, we have the matrix $(2,2)^T$ That's a map from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ that sends $x\mapsto(2x,2x)^T$, and that map is injective. If you pick a different value of $t$, you get a different injective linear map.

Comment: Ah, Now I See what you mean. you mean t fixed and then the matrix as transformation Matrix with Respect to the standard basis.    —  for the other maping which I thought of: it is injective since $(2t, 3t^2-1)=(2s,3s^2-1)$ Implies t=s, right?

Comment: Not quite, although it is injective in that sense. It's this: If we set $t=1$, we get $(2,2)$, right? That isn't just a point in $\Bbb{R}^2$, it's a map from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$. It sends $x\mapsto(2x,2x)$, and it's injective because $(2x,2x)=(2y,2y)\implies x=y$.

Comment: More than that, for any value of $t$, the resulting linear map is injective. Indeed, the only way for a linear map from $\Bbb{R}$ not to be injective would be if it were the $0$ map. That's why it's important that there is no value of $t$ for which $(2t,3t^2-1)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Injectivity of derivative would mean that the rank has to be 1, that of the domain, not target space. To have rank 1 is equivalent to the derivative being nonzero here. Now, all you need to verify is that this derivative is never $(0,0)$, which is easy:
To have the first coordinate zero, we must have $t=0$, in which case the second coordinate is not zero. So, you'll never get $(0,0)$ for the derivative for any value of $t$.